# when i run my client program it doesn't connect with my server

Tags: c, sockets

this client and server program compiles successfully. run the server it waits for client connection.
but when i run this client program it always shows "connection failed..."
i don't understand why...

server.c

```
int main()
{

  struct sockaddr_in main_server, cli_1_server, cli_2_server;
  int main_sock, cli_1_sock, cli_2_sock;
  int Len;
  char arv_msg[MAXSZ];
  //char client_name[20];
 // FILE *fp;
  //short int RcvByte_1 = 0, RcvByte_2 = 0;

  if( ( main_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) ) < 0 )
  {
    printf("socket creation failed...\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  main_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  main_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  main_server.sin_port = htons(10000);

  if( ( bind( main_sock, (SA *)&main_server, sizeof(main_server) ) ) < 0)
  {
    printf("binding failed...\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  printf("Listining...\n");
  listen(main_sock, WAITING);
  Len = sizeof(cli_1_server);

  if( ( cli_1_sock = accept( main_sock, (SA *)&cli_1_server, &Len ) ) <0)
  {
    printf("Client 1 request failed...\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  printf("client 1 connected...\n");

}
```

client.c

```
int main()
{

  struct sockaddr_in main_server;
  int cli_1_sock;
  char snd_msg[MAXSZ], rcv_msg[MAXSZ];
  int n = 0;

  if( ( cli_1_sock = (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) ) == -1 )
  {
    printf("socket creation failed...\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  main_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  main_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  main_server.sin_port = htons(10000);

  if( ( connect(cli_1_sock, (SA *)&main_server,sizeof(main_server)))==-1)
  {
    printf("connection failed...\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  printf("connected\n");

}
```

this is my server and client..program

Answer (score 0):

change

```
cli_1_sock = (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
```

to

```
cli_1_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
```

Comment: ohhhh......heheheh....i read the code again and again...bt can't.....heheh thanku..thanku..